# Best Practices - Reading records from one database, validate and insert into another database using Quartz in clustered environment

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

We have a requirement where we have millions of records in source database and we need to read this data, validate and insert into destination database.This needs to be done as per configured scheduled time (say on daily basis at 12.00 PM.). We are looking to achieve SLA where we can process 500k records within 30 minutes. We have clustered environment having 4 JVMs.

**Technology Stack:** Oracle, Spring-Quartz

We have designed our solution using Spring-Quartz where one job is responsible to assign work to other jobs.

**Quartz Job (Work Distributor)** : The responsibility of this job is to assign the work to different workers/jobs. This table will read record range and log the range along with worker JVM (who will process the data) in temp table. This will be only run by one of the 4 JVMs. If one JVM triggers it, another JVM will not run this job.

**Quartz Job (Workers)** : The responsibility of this job is to read work distributor's temp table and get the range which is assigned to the JVM where this job is running. This job will fetch the data from source database as per assigned range, perform validation and insert into destination database. This job will spawn multiple threads to process the  no. of assigned records.

I have posted this question just to get thoughts on this approach. Is there any other approach which is more robust?

Comment: Seems good, but your reliance on database might be your bottleneck. If you want performance, then I would recommend using Redis. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please explain, where exactly Redis can be fit in this scenarios?

Comment: You can directly insert objects in Redis with a key value and retrieve it, instead of reading/writing to database. Redis is highly distributed and is meant for performance. You can even give a pattern to keys so you can retrieve multiple objects in bulk and process it. If you have multiple CPU', then you can benefit from Redis's master-slave mechanism and backup is just in one rdb file to copy and paste across different machines.

Comment: But using database for a high performance oriented applications when there is a solution possible is not a good idea, is what I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experience, to make your life easier, [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) allows you to program your ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) Application as a single worker, but underneath will distribute the workload for you, the data can also be resilient and is able to keep running if a cluster fails.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure much about Apache Spark. But I will for sure look into it and see how this can help in our case.